# xampp does not recognize php file

Tags: php, apache, magento, phpmyadmin

I have downloaded magento from bitnami a month ago on my windows 8, now I wanted to install xampp to run my php files and test them I have some confusing issues

1:When I open my php file after installing xampp its not opening as a php file and I have to choose options to open it with notepad,php file is appearing same as nothing happens on installing xampp.

2.Magento has accessed the ports required so if i try to test xampp like this localhost/ it opens page for magento successful installation and not xampp..  I changed the port from 80 to 81 and accessed localhost like this correctly localhost:81/ but when I try to access phpmyadmin its not giving me access to the server with root and no password also I have changed AllowNoPassword true already.I have changed the port to 3310 now how  to access phpmyadmin as if I write localhot:3310/phpmyadmin it force downoads a file saying "PACKETS ARE NOT IN ORDER"
I am feeling that there might be some thing conflict among the two installations the question is as I have installed magento already what is the best way t run and test my php file
Thanks in advance